# Arrays in Methods and Returning to Main

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to go from a method back to main. For example, I want to check if number passes a certain criteria;  I would perform a test in a different method and if it returns true, I want to continue using that number back in main. How can go from one method to main again in a continuous loop? I tried calling the main method but the program displays a message for error.

The way my project is set out is that a menu appears for the user to enter a postal code. The menu has many options to add, quit, or view their codes. Once they have added their postal code and it is valid, how can I loop it back to main with the menu appearing again, performing the same functions?

Small section from main:

```
 if (decision.Equals("A"))
   {

     Console.Write("\n");
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter your postal code: ");

      for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
  {
      postalcodez = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

if (isValid(postalcodez, i, number, j, num))
{

 postalcode[i] = postalcodez;
 Console.WriteLine("It worked!");
 Console.ReadLine();


}

 }

}
```

Now it goes through the method to check for conditions. If it returns true, how can I make it go back to main?

```
 public static bool isValid(string postalcodez, int i, int number, int j, int num)
    {
        if (postalcodez.Length > 7 || postalcodez.Length < 7)
        {
            return false;

        }

        if (postalcodez[0].ToString().Equals("W") || postalcodez[0].ToString().Equals("Z"))
        {

            return false;

        }

        if (postalcodez.Length.Equals(7))
        {

            if (postalcodez[3].ToString().Equals(" "))
            {
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Another question is that how can I make an array so that I can set a condition for a specific character number. Instead of doing this ( where I hard code specific digits) I want it that the 1, 4 and 6th character must be a certain value :

```
      if (postalcodez[1].ToString().Equals(0) || postalcodez[1].ToString().Equals(1) || postalcodez[1].ToString().Equals(2) || postalcodez[1].ToString().Equals(3) || postalcodez[1].ToString().Equals(4))
            {

                return true;

            }
```

Since this is for school, I can use any special functions to resolve the issue. It has to be very basic.

Comment: Add your code here.

Comment: Could you show the code you tried? Without seeing that, there is no way we can deduce how to help you.

Comment: Would you like the full project? Or small pieces?

Comment: Just show the part of the code which you need help with. Make sure it is enough code so we can replicate your issue. At least try.

Comment: You should take some time to *really think out what it is you are trying to accomplish*, and then post a [mcve] which shows roughly what you attempted, and try not to include lots of calls to other functions and libraries if they aren't involved in the problem.

Comment: Your methods need to return more than one variable.  There are 3 methods for handling this 1) Return a KeyValuePair<bool,int> which will return two variables 2) In the parameter list make variable(s) that are prefix with either 'out' or 'ref' 3) Return a class object or structure.

Comment: When you call a method from Main, the code in the method will execute. When the method completes, execution will automatically return to Main.

Comment: The way my project is set out is that a menu appears for the user to enter a postal code. The menu has many options to add, quit, or view their codes. Once they have added their postal code and it is valid, how can I loop it back to main with the menu appearing again, performing the same functions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a bit of a misunderstanding of what Main() actually is. Main() is, in effect, your entire application. Main is the root that everything will flow back to when the current call stack finishes resolving, and if there are no additional statements after that point, Main will complete, and the application will close. When you call methods from Main, when they return a value (if not void), you are then back inside of Main.

Based on what you have stated is your need, here is a very basic example of what will happen - the flow of the code should be reasonably clear:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int number = 5;
    bool isValid = VerifyNumber(number);
    if (!isValid)
        Console.WriteLine("Not valid.");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Valid.");

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static bool VerifyNumber(int number)
{
    return number > 2;
}
```

Things to take note of:

Since the method being called from Main has an argument, that argument is provided from inside of Main. This means that when the method finishes, Main still has access to that value.

The output of the method is stored so that work can be done inside of Main based on it.